# Hide file extension

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp-classic, web-config

I want to remove the file-extension (like `.html`) for users of IE, FF and google Chrome.

I have a hyperlink like : `www.coco/New.html`.

When I type `www.coco/New` I receive a 404 error.

I want users to only type `www.coco/New` in all browsers.

What can I do in ASP " visual web developer "?
Is it possible to adding some code in project "Web.config"?

Comment: You tagged this as classic ASP and ASP.NET. Which is it?

Comment: What have you tried, what did google/stackoverflow tell you? Psst...possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223750/how-do-net-sites-hide-aspx-extension-of-their-files points to http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24347759/304683) should be your moment of zen for `ASP.Net WebPages` - it was for me :) In fact I could even add `Razor` code to any HTML page, though without `Intellisense` :)

Comment: You need URL Rewrite mechanism, it's on the server level, usually without actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change / duplicate the file name as index.html then save it in a folder named New so the url will be www.coco/New/index.html then the page will also display when www.coco/New is typed